# Combining grpup_by and grepl in a dplyr workflow

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I would like to achieve a simple task of passing a set of columns to `group_by` in `dplyr` using `grepl` or an equivalent function matching phrase.

The problem can be easily illustrated with use of the example below:

## Example

### Data

```
set.seed(1)
dta <- data.frame(firstThing = 1:10, secondThing = 20:29)
for (i in 3:20) {
  dta[,i] <- runif(n = 10)
  colnames(dta)[i] <- paste0("KeyMeasureWithValues", i)
}
```

### Grouping

I would like to group the `dta` `data.frame` by all variables that have the *measure* word in the variable name, for example:

```
dta %<>%
  group_by(grep(pattern = "measure", x = colnames(.),
                value = TRUE, ignore.case = TRUE)) %>% 
  tally()
```

However, the code returns an error message:

```
Error: wrong result size (18), expected 10 or 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `.dots` along with `group_by_`

```
dta %>% 
    group_by_(.dots=grep(pattern = "measure", x = colnames(.), 
               value = TRUE, ignore.case=TRUE)) %>%
    tally()
```

Comment: Thanks very much, another reminder that I should read more on the [NSE](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/nse.html).